# Use Scratch 2 (and NOT Scratch 3) on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, scratch

I want to use Scratch 2 on raspbian. I googled and found that latest raspbian buster comes with Scratch 3 (which I don't want to use). Based on further searches, I have now downloaded raspbian Stretch (2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch).

If I install above raspbian image afresh, how can I have the latest OS updates (e.g. security fixes) but keep using Scratch 2.
I mean will it automatically upgrade to buster?

PS: I want to use the offline and not the online version of scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what Scratch version is available on what Raspbian version but from your question I assume only Scratch 3 is available from the repository of Raspbian Buster and only Scratch 2 is available from the repository of Raspbian Stretch. If you use Raspbian Stretch and only use its repository and install Scratch 2 from it then `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` will do no harm and you should do it regulary. It only upgrades installed packages and keeps Scratch 2 up to date as long as Stretch is supported. If you want to mix up software packages from repositories you may have a look at [pinning packages](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration) to avoid its upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/scratch-3-desktop-for-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi/

You can install ANY version of Scratch 1, 2 or 3 on Buster in Recommended Software.

You can also remove unwanted versions.

Comment: In current Raspberry Pi OS, only Scratch 3 is showing in recommended software.

Answer (score -1):

If you do `apt-get upgrade` it will be upgrade.  So the answer is simple:  Don't do that command.

The upgrade command simply selects everything that can be upgraded and upgrades them.  If you pick and choose what to upgrade, you only get that.

If you use aptitude, you can "hold" the one you don't want to upgrade.  While this isn't perfect, you can then do a limit (key lowercase L) like `~U !~ahold` and it will show you everything that can be upgraded except those you have explicitly held.

Comment: and I won't get security updates without doing apt-get upgrade. right?

Comment: security update are not special in any way, except perhaps for coming from a security repository.  You get them because you've installed the update of the relevant package, not from explicitly using the "upgrade" command.  The point is, you NEVER need to do "apt-get upgrade".  "apt-get update" (or equivalent) is another matter.  It is about finding out what is available.

Comment: well, I found this on the RPi website for [updating/upgrading](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) (apt-get upgrade):
`Generally speaking, doing this regularly will keep your installation up to date for the particular major Raspbian release you are using (e.g. Stretch). It will not update from one major release to another, for example, Stretch to Buster.`

Comment: so I should hopefully be ok

Comment: If you want to automatically switch debian/raspbian releases, configure to use "stable" or "testing" instead of "Stretch" or "Buster".

Comment: -1. Scratch 1, Scratch 2, and Scratch 3 are separate packages. Upgrading will never remove Scratch 2 and replace it with Scratch 3. Additionally it **is terrible practice to advise a beginner to not ever run `sudo apt upgrade`**.

Comment: @Botspot  Personally, I think it bad form to use "sudo" at all.  I also feel one should have some idea what one is upgrading, selecting what one wants and doesn't want, or at least knowing what is upgrading.  And I did recommend the controlled equivalent.  I will admit, the hold command of aptitude is also particularly useful.  As for scratch...  it looks like the latest available is 1.4.0.6, and the scratch web site says it isn't available for linux.  Thus, I'm not sure about the "scratch" versions at all.

Comment: @DavidG. Ignore the scratch website. run this on a RPi: `apt search scratch --names-only`. You will see thse packages: `scratch`, `scratch2`, and `scratch3`.